# How to use mutual information to determine a random sequence length

Tags: information-theory

Assume that you receive a noise-free random sequence $Xk, k∈Z$. You know that the elements have memory of length $L$, but $L$ is unknown.

How can we use mutual information to identify $L$? We assume we can measure the exact mutual information $I(Xk;Xl)$ for any values of $k$ and $l$ without error.